# Compare two lists of different class and remove based on property

Tags: python, list, loops

I am looking for an efficient way to compare two list of class.

I have two class Invoice and Event.
I have event.invoice_id that is referencing invoice.id.
Both list have 30k rows.

What I want to do is remove invoices where the related event is not found in the event list.

Here is my code but it's really slow, is there a way to do it faster?

```
for invoice in invoices:
        found = [tEv for tEv in pEvents if docExistsInEvents(invoice,tEv)]
        if not found:
            invoices.remove(invoice)

def docExistsInEvents(pInvoice, pEvent):
    if pInvoice.id == pEvent.invoice_id:
        return True
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `set`:

```
# assuming `invoices` contains all invoices and `events` all events

# build a set containing all relevant ids
event_invoice_ids = {event.invoice_id for event in events}

# create a list with only the relevant data by filtering invoices
# on the pre-built set of invoice ids
relevant_invoices = [invoice for invoice in invoices if invoice.id
                     in event_invoice_ids]
```

It will be much faster because the search is done by the invoice id's hash.

Comment: Or the other way around. Filter out invoices whose event_id is not in the event list, which is what the question asker is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the solution !